# Firebase Returning user object after account creation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im trying to create a user within Firebase and then create a user profile within the database on a  web server. I have implemented the following code which creates the user quite nicely. However im not sure on how to receive the user id (which i need for a unique ID) to create the database structure. Is there a way to return a user object when the createUserWithEmailAndPassword is called?

I have tried to implement a `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`function but i then receive a timeout error

If you havn't gathered this is for a web app.

```
<script>
function createUser() {
var Result = "true";
var textUser = document.getElementById('userName').value;
var textPassword = document.getElementById('userPassword').value;
var textAccountID = document.getElementById('accountRef').value;
var textDateCreated = document.getElementById('dateCreated').value;
var textDisplayName = document.getElementById('displayName').value;
var UID;

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(textUser, textPassword).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  return Result = "false";
  // ...
});

writeUserData(UID, textDisplayName, textAccountID, textDateCreated);

return Result;

}

function writeUserData(userId, displayName, accountID, dateCreated) {
  firebase.database().ref('User/' + userId).set({
  userId:{
    AccountID: accountID,
    Created: dateCreated,
    Name: displayName}
  });
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In order to get the user id  in the client side you should do this:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(textUser, textPassword)
.then(function(user){
  console.log('uid',user.uid)

  //Here if you want you can sign in the user
}).catch(function(error) {
    //Handle error
});
```

as it is described here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Returns
non-null firebase.Promise containing non-null firebase.User

Comment: From the doc you link: "On successful creation of the user account, this user will also be signed in to your application."

Comment: You are correct...a change i didn't catch from the old version... corrected thanks

Comment: Yeah, that behavior has changed completely. I get bitten by it all the time.

Comment: im receiving a auth/network-request-failed error implementing the above. Debugging suggest that the .then promise is not called

Comment: If the then is not executed , the catch will...can you show the log of the error received in the catch???

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. After account creation, I'm redirecting back into my main index.html but it appears I am not signed in.

Comment: auth/network-request-failed   : Thrown if a network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

Comment: can someone replicate it?

Comment: Are you on a slow or unstable network? Try to test on other devices to make sure the problem is only local. Also, check your network log for the request status.

Comment: Hey Script Kitty, just in case you are not doing so, are you making sure to redirect back to your index.html when the promise resolves: firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(function(user) { //redirect here });

Comment: Some strange results here, the network error persisted while i was using a <form action="return createUser();"> method with a submit button. I removed the action from the form and changed the submit input for a button input and it worked. I think the form in my case was pushing the user to an alternative url which included the get request from the form. Hope this help someone else

Comment: Has the promise returned changed?  I'm not able to reach user.uid, instead I have to do something like data.user.uid.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in the links, I don't see explicit reference describing the `uid`. Is it truly unique? random? How does Google/Firebase generate it? Still searching....

Comment: I had to use user.user.uid

Answer (score 21):

Looks like firebase has made some changes on this method. The accepted solution needs a little fix:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(textUser, textPassword)
.then(function(data){
  console.log('uid',data.user.uid)

  //Here if you want you can sign in the user
}).catch(function(error) {
    //Handle error
});
```

Now you get to acces the user via data.user

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is correct as per new changes. Thanks, saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` function returns a so-called Promise, which has methods `catch()` and `then()`. You're already using `catch()` to handle problems. To handle "non-problems", you need to use `then()`:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(textUser, textPassword)
.then(function(user) {
  console.log(user); // see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
})
.catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  return Result = "false";
  // ...
});
```

See the reference documentation for [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) and for [firebase.User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User).

Comment: im receiving a auth/network-request-failed error implementing the above. Debugging suggest that the .then promise is not called

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value).then(function (user) {
            //var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            alert('Cadastro feito com sucesso!', "success");
            console.log("New user Id: "+ user.uid);

          }).catch(function (error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
              alert('A senha é muito fraca.', "warning");
              //alert('A senha é muito fraca.');
            } else if (errorMessage == "The email address is already in use by another account.") {
                errorMsg = "Esse email já está sendo usado por outra conta";
                alert(errorMsg, "danger");

              //alert(errorMessage);
            }else{
              alert(errorMessage);
            }
            
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
          });
```