# Save user info into database just after registration in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save a newly created user's info into Firestore using the uid as the document id. The problem I encounter comes after the creation of the user, in order to save his information into the Firestore collection after creation.
Here is what I have already tried:

```
 const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Users');

 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password).then(function(user){
  usersRef.doc(`${user.uid}`).set({
    firstName: values.firstName,
    lastName: values.lastName,
    username: values.username,
    uid: user.uid
  })
}).catch(function(error){
  // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
      alert('The password is too weak.');
    } else {
      alert(errorMessage);
    }
    console.log(error);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
});
```

The code is expected to save the user's info after creation, but it causes the following error :
The collection document ID cannot be undefined or so

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52750518/628699

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method you're using using returns [`Promise<UserCredential>`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#usercredential). Your code should be:

```
const usersRef = firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('Users');

firebase
  .auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
  .then(function(userCredential) {
    usersRef
      .doc(`${userCredential.user.uid}`)
      .set({
        firstName: values.firstName,
        lastName: values.lastName,
        username: values.username,
        uid: userCredential.user.uid
      })
      ...
```

Comment: Ok let me give it a try